# Youtube-dl refuses to run in background

Tags: command-line, bash, youtube-dl, redirect, background-process

I run `youtube-dl` in background by putting `&` after the command.
The problem is it doesn't care that I put it in the background and keeps printing information in the terminal.

Not only does it refuse to stop with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, it just doesn't do anything other than showing these messages. To stop it I must close the terminal.

Here is what happens exactly:

```
mohamed@Smithers:~$ clear
mohamed@Smithers:~$ youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMQsYSuw8hw &
[1] 2028
mohamed@Smithers:~$ [youtube] LMQsYSuw8hw: Downloading webpage
[youtube] LMQsYSuw8hw: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] LMQsYSuw8hw: Extracting video information
[youtube] LMQsYSuw8hw: Downloading MPD manifest
WARNING: Requested formats are incompatible for merge and will be merged into mkv.
[download] Resuming download at byte 11440128
[download] Destination: I Was On Japanese TV... and I F#%KING HATED IT.-LMQsYSuw8hw.f137.mp4
[download]   4.8% of 231.85MiB at 199.01KiB/s ETA 18:56^C
mohamed@Smithers:~$ ^C
mohamed@Smithers:~$ ^C
[download]   4.8% of 231.85MiB at 136.95KiB/s ETA 27:30^C
mohamed@Smithers:~$ ^C
mohamed@Smithers:~$ ^C
mohamed@Smithers:~$ ^C
mohamed@Smithers:~$ ^C
[download]   5.0% of 231.85MiB at 127.41KiB/s ETA 29:31^C
mohamed@Smithers:~$ ^C
mohamed@Smithers:~$ ^C
mohamed@Smithers:~$ ^C
mohamed@Smithers:~$ ^C
mohamed@Smithers:~$ ^C
mohamed@Smithers:~$ ^C
mohamed@Smithers:~$ ^C
mohamed@Smithers:~$ ^C
mohamed@Smithers:~$ ^C
[download]   5.0% of 231.85MiB at 111.38KiB/s ETA 33:44^C
mohamed@Smithers:~$ ^C
[download]   5.0% of 231.85MiB at 111.21KiB/s ETA 33:47^C
mohamed@Smithers:~$ ^C
[download]   5.1% of 231.85MiB at 116.77KiB/s ETA 32:09^C

[download]   5.5% of 231.85MiB at 108.71KiB/s ETA 34:24^C

[download]   5.6% of 231.85MiB at 76.68KiB/s ETA 48:41
```

Comment: To stop background jobs, you first need to bring them to foreground by `fg` command. If you do want background jobs with no output on terminal, just run `command > /dev/null 2>&1 &`; if you want to completely disconnect them from terminal,  run `nohup command &`; this will keep the command running, even if you close the terminal, and append the output to a file named `nohup.out`.

Comment: @ridgy You might want to post an answer about that. [My answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/865572/22949) focuses on how to run `youtube-dl` differently, and does include information about redirection, but it doesn't address how the OP should *fix* the problem after running it in a way they don't want (as your comment does), nor does it give any information about job control. I'm somewhat reluctant to expand my own answer since it's already rather complicated and because I don't want to remove the primary focus from `youtube-dl`'s options too much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`youtube-dl` is running in the background, but it is still sending output to your terminal, and producing quite a lot of it to inform you of its progress. There are a number of ways to change this, but you'll probably either want to make `youtube-dl` *produce* less output, or cause its output to be sent to a file (or discarded altogether) instead of appearing in your terminal.

#### Way 1: Run `youtube-dl -q` to suppress status messages.

If you don't want to see the progress messages, you can pass the `-q` flag (or `--quiet`, which does the same thing) to the `youtube-dl` command:

```
youtube-dl -q https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZ-ElsvYKyo &
```

You'd have to replace that URL with whatever you're trying to download, of course. Some messages may still be printed, including errors and warnings. But it's likely you want to see those.

If you don't want `youtube-dl` to produce any warnings, you can run `youtube-dl` with the `--no-warnings` flag. I don't suggest doing that, though, unless you're sure that's what you want.

```
youtube-dl -q --no-warnings https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZ-ElsvYKyo &
```

To learn more about the command-line options accepted by `youtube-dl`, you can run `man youtube-dl` or [read its manual page online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/youtube-dl.1.html).

#### Way 2: Redirect standard output of `youtube-dl` to a file.

To append the output to `dl.log` in the current directory (you can name this what you want, and it will be created if it doesn't already exist), run:

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZ-ElsvYKyo >> dl.log &
```

If you want to *overwrite* `dl.log` instead of appending text to the end, use `>` instead of `>>`:

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZ-ElsvYKyo > dl.log &
```

Normal output will then be redirected to `dl.log` (or whatever file you tell it to use). Error output, however, will still be shown on your terminal. For example, when I ran that command, I got one warning printed to my terminal:

```
ek@Io:~$ youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZ-ElsvYKyo >> dl.log &
[1] 14456
ek@Io:~$ WARNING: Requested formats are incompatible for merge and will be merged into mkv
```

Everything else went into the log file:

```
ek@Io:~$ cat dl.log
[youtube] NZ-ElsvYKyo: Downloading webpage
[youtube] NZ-ElsvYKyo: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] NZ-ElsvYKyo: Extracting video information
[youtube] NZ-ElsvYKyo: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Destination: Lecture 1 _ Topics in String Theory-NZ-ElsvYKyo.f244.webm
[download]  23.2% of 359.52MiB at 204.49KiB/s ETA 23:02ek@Io:~$
```

You can view the output with `cat` (as I've done above) at any time, to check the progress.

When you run `youtube-dl` without `-q`, it produces output that is primarily meant for a terminal. This output includes control characters that tell a terminal to erase the previous progress message, so that it may be visually replaced with the new progress message. Some ways of viewing the file, like `cat dl.log`, will not show the "erased" messages or the control characters. They're still part of the file, though, and you can view them with some other utilities; for example, `view dl.log` works.

#### Way 2a: Redirect the output to `/dev/null` to get rid of it.

If you want the output to just be discarded rather than saved in an actual file, then you can redirect it to [`/dev/null`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device):

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZ-ElsvYKyo > /dev/null &
```

With `/dev/null`, it doesn't matter if you "overwrite" (`>`) or "append" (`>>`).

This is a handy technique in general, though probably unnecessary with `youtube-dl`. If you want to suppress progress, you can just run `youtube-dl -q` instead.

#### Way 3: Redirect standard error, too.

[Regular output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) and [error output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29) are separate. It's common for `youtube-dl` to produce both. The above method redirected only standard output. You can also redirect standard error. There's a lot you can do with redirection, including redirecting the two output streams to separate files. For our purposes here, I'll just show how to send both standard output and standard error to the same file:

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZ-ElsvYKyo &>> dl.log &
```

When I ran that, my shell showed only

```
[2] 15009
```

...and both regular output and error output appeared in `dl.log`:

```
ek@Io:~$ cat dl.log
[youtube] NZ-ElsvYKyo: Downloading webpage
[youtube] NZ-ElsvYKyo: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] NZ-ElsvYKyo: Extracting video information
[youtube] NZ-ElsvYKyo: Downloading MPD manifest
WARNING: Requested formats are incompatible for merge and will be merged into mkv.
[download] Destination: Lecture 1 _ Topics in String Theory-NZ-ElsvYKyo.f244.webm
[download]   0.0% of 359.52MiB at 107.65KiB/s ETA 56:59ek@Io:~$
```

The above example used `&>>`, which appends to `dl.log`. To overwrite the file instead, use `&>` (or `>&`, which also works) instead of `&>>`:

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZ-ElsvYKyo &> dl.log &
```

#### Way 3a: Redirect both normal and error output to `/dev/null`.

If you really want to, you can redirect both standard output and standard error to `/dev/null` so it is all simply discarded:

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZ-ElsvYKyo &> /dev/null &
```

You probably want to see actual error messages, though. If it's just status messages and warnings you don't want, then you don't need any redirection. In that case you can use `youtube-dl -q --no-warnings` as described above. (See Way 1.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that none of the advice worked - or applies - from Eliah's answer.

Not sure why the library does not seem to support the quiet option for the

self.to_screen('Downloading just video %s because of --no-playlist' % video_id)

outputs as one might expect them to operate...

The section of code here

```
def report_download_webpage(self, video_id):
    """Report webpage download."""
    self.to_screen('%s: Downloading webpage' % video_id)
```

in Lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\Common.py is the culprit of the out in the self.to_screen call.

if you elide the self.to_screen calls in whatever downloader you are calling with #'s  - example site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\youtube.py This is will elide the various outputs for good.